# doesnt work: NSToolbarItem + custom view + setAction:

Tags: cocoa, nsview, nsbutton, nstoolbaritem

I'm adding a toolbar programmatically inside an interface inheriting `NSObject <NSToolbarDelegate>`, and implementing these methods:

```
- (NSToolbarItem*)toolbar:(NSToolbar*)toolbar itemForItemIdentifier:(NSString *)itemIdentifier willBeInsertedIntoToolbar:(BOOL)willBeInsertedIntoToolbar;
- (NSArray *)toolbarSelectableItemIdentifiers: (NSToolbar*)toolbar
- (NSArray *)toolbarAllowedItemIdentifiers:(NSToolbar *)toolbar 
- (NSArray *)toolbarDefaultItemIdentifiers:(NSToolbar *)toolbar
```

I also add a  button by calling `setView` on a NSToolbarItem. This view contains an NSButton and is in the .XIB interface.

However, `setAction` on the same item does not work, due to reason described at http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/291782-nstoolbaritem-custom-view-setaction.html#291783.

How do I implement this solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the target and action of the `NSButton` in the nib file itself, or if you need to do it programmatically, then create an `IBOutlet` to the `NSButton` and do it in code.

When you use an `NSButton` in a toolbar item, it effectively acts like an `NSButton` would anywhere else in your interface, rather than as an `NSToolbarItem` per se. For example, you won't be able to easily disable or enable the button through the use of the standard `-validateToolbarItem:` or `-validateUserInterfaceItem:`; rather, you'll need to have an `IBOutlet` to the button in question, or otherwise use bindings to enable or disable the button.

Comment: Thank you for this.  Is this in the docs somewhere?  Been banging my head against a wall.